# How to override classes in lib/Varien directory?

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I want to override `\lib\Varien\Data\Collection\Db.php`. I know how to override this by creating the same file path in local code pool. I want to know is it possible to override this class same way we overriding models, blocks inside our modules? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can **not** rewrite `Varien_Data_Collection_Db` the dynamic way like you do with models, etc.

The reason is simple: all appropriate Magento models use `Varien_Data_Collection_Db` as a base class and *literally* extend it:

```
abstract class Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract extends Varien_Data_Collection_Db {}
abstract class Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract extends Varien_Data_Collection_Db {}
class Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Sale_Collection extends Varien_Data_Collection_Db {}
```

Copying the class to the `local` or `community` code pool is the way to go.

Comment: I Was confused about this. Thank you Jürgen Thelen.